# img-crop is not working properly on production

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-img-crop

I am using `ng-img-crop` in my jhipster project following steps as mentioned in [here](https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop). In my developer mode (ie. in STS) it is working properly. But when I create WAR file of my jhipster project it is not behaving properly.

> **The differences can be observed by the images**
>
> 1. [STS Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwV1m.png) Screenshot of the page when run from STS
> 2. [WAR File Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAEgT.png)  Screenshot of the page when run from WAR file

The significant difference that I have found on selecting the same image  is: The canvas ( highlighted in the images under inspect element section ) is taking margin-top and margin-left by it self.

**Before selecting the image**(in both pages from STS and WAR):

```
<div class="cropArea ng-hide" ng-show="showCropDiv">
    <img-crop image="myImage" result-image="myCroppedImage" area-type="square" change-on-fly="false" class="ng-isolate-scope">
        <canvas width="0" height="0" style="margin-top: 0px;"></canvas>
    </img-crop>
</div>
```

**After selecting the image**

In the page from STS:

```
<div class="cropArea" ng-show="showCropDiv">
    <img-crop image="myImage" result-image="myCroppedImage" area-type="square" change-on-fly="false" class="ng-isolate-scope">
         <canvas width="500" height="333" style="margin-top: -166.682px; margin-left: -250px; cursor: default;"></canvas>
    </img-crop>
</div>
```

and in the page from WAR File:

```
<div class="cropArea" ng-show="showCropDiv">
    <img-crop image="myImage" result-image="myCroppedImage" area-type="square" change-on-fly="false" class="ng-isolate-scope">
       <canvas width="149" height="100" style="margin-top: -50px; margin-left: -74.9932px; cursor: default;"></canvas>
   </img-crop>
</div>
```

Is there any way to fix this Issue? Any suggestion or pointers would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.